# PHP Mail Headers are Being Sent Within The Body

Tags: php, email

```
function sendEmail($address,$subject,$message)
{
    $headers = "Reply-To: miloAds Team <admin@miloads.com>\r";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: miloAds Team <admin@miloads.com>\r";
    $headers .= "From: miloAds Team <admin@miloads.com>\r"; 
    $headers .= "Organization: Milonas Media LLC\r";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r";

    mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

When sending out an email, the header is appearing in the body.

Comment: By the way, `Return-Path` isn't a header you can set, the mail server must set it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing each of the `\r` escapes to `\r\n` and see if that helps.

Quoth the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> **additional_headers** (optional)
>
> ```
> String to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc).
> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).
> ```

Make sure to *not* include the trailing `\r\n` on the last header either.

Also make sure to strip any newlines from the `$subject` as that could cause problems.  See if those help.

Comment: I have used just `\n`, which has always worked just fine for me.

Comment: @MatthewJordan Also from the manual... `Note:

If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.`

Comment: Can you view the message source in your mail client so you can see the full, raw message content.  You should see a header that has 2 newlines after it which separates the headers from the body.

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` to `\r`, i.e. `\r\n` and remove the last one:

```
function sendEmail($address,$subject,$message)
{
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: miloAds Team <admin@miloads.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: miloAds Team <admin@miloads.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Organization: Milonas Media LLC\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion();

    mail($address, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```